# ubuntu 20.04 : no wifi no ethernet, no touchpud detected after the command apt-get purge nvidia*

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, nvidia, touchpad

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, i moved recently from win10, i wanted to update nvidia drivers on my Legion 7 15MH05, so i did thos steps:

I opened Terminal, and i did thos commands:

1-"ubuntu-drivers devices"

2-"sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall"

3-"sudo apt install nvidia-driver-510"

4-"sudo reboot"

after that my computer didn't start, it stack on the name of it : LEGION
So i go to

1- "Advanced options for Ubuntu"

2- (recovery mode)

3- in Recovery menu i choosed "root"

i did thos commands:

4- "apt-get purge nvidia*"

5-"reboot"

After that my computer start normaly, but my touchpad didnt work anymore, also i cant connect to the internet.
Can anyone help me figuring out what should i do.
Thankyou.

[No internet icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2cgc.jpg)

[the ethernet cable is already plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrmqf.jpg)

["sudo lshw -C network"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7KFp.jpg)

Comment: #3 is redundant after  #2 and with Ubuntu 20.04 you can and should select to install 3rd party drivers, firmware, etc. during the OS installation. No need to manually install Nvidia drivers after the fact. Keep in mind you need to either disable Secure Boot in UEFI or sign the Nvidia drivers with MOKutil (a pop-up will show if you select the aforementioned option during installation with Secure Boot enabled. Right now the easies option is to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: I just go to Advanced options for Ubuntu, I choose an old recovery and it work, what I should do now

Comment: Again, disable Secure Boot in UEFI, reinstall Nvidia drivers.

Comment: I already disabled secure boot in UEFI, but is there any secure méthode to reinstall Nvidia drivers so my system don't crash again?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers, my computer works well now with these steps:

1. I boot my computer while holding the <kbd>F12</kbd> key.
2. When the menu shows, I choose "Advanced options for Ubuntu"
3. I click "Ubuntu … (recovery mode)"
4. In terminal "sudo apt-get update"
5. Reboot the computer